# How to rewrite a goal using function definition?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have this code:

```
Module Type tDecType.
  Parameter T: Type.
  Parameter is_eq: T -> T -> bool.
  Axiom is_eq_reflexivity: forall x, is_eq x x = true.
  Axiom is_eq_equality: forall x y, is_eq x y = true -> x = y.
End tDecType.

Module NAT <: tDecType.
  Definition T := nat.
  Definition is_eq (x: T) y := x = y.

  Lemma is_eq_reflexivity:
    forall x,
    is_eq x x = True.
  Proof.
    intro x.
    ?
```

And I want to rewrite the current subgoal by using the is_eq definition. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can use the `unfold` tactic like so: `unfold is_eq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem is your definition of `is_eq`. Notice that in your module declaration, you have specified the following type for `is_eq`

```
is_eq : T -> T -> bool
```

but in module `NAT` you used the propositional equality, whose type is:

```
= : forall T, T -> T -> Prop
```

I have fixed your code by setting another version of `is_eq`, based on standard library boolean equality for natural numbers, and doing a simple inductive proof for reflexivity.

```
 ...  same code as before.
 Require Import Nat.

 Definition is_eq (x: T) y := eqb x y.

 Lemma is_eq_reflexivity : forall x, is_eq x x = true.
 Proof.
   induction x ; simpl ; auto.
 Qed.
```